# Problems with Stripe TextUtils

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

Hello guys I hope everyone is very well, I had the following problem and I could not move forward with my app, I have the following error

```
Error:(32, 31) error: cannot find symbol class TextUtils
Error:(367, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(504, 14) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(505, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(507, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(509, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(511, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(513, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(515, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable TextUtils
Error:(535, 13) error: no suitable constructor found for Stripe(no arguments)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And the source code of the error is as follows

```
import com.stripe.android.util.TextUtils;
```

and

```
public String getType(String number) {
        if (!TextUtils.isBlank(number)) {
            if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_AMERICAN_EXPRESS)) {
                return AMERICAN_EXPRESS;
            } else if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DISCOVER)) {
                return DISCOVER;
            } else if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_JCB)) {
                return JCB;
            } else if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DINERS_CLUB)) {
                return DINERS_CLUB;
            } else if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_VISA)) {
                return VISA;
            } else if (TextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_MASTERCARD)) {
                return MASTERCARD;
            } else {
                return UNKNOWN;
```

I thank you very much if you can help me with this problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please import

> com.stripe.android.util.StripeTextUtils;

and use  `StripeTextUtils instead of TextUtils`

```
public String getType(String number) {
        if (!StripeTextUtils.isBlank(number)) {
            if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_AMERICAN_EXPRESS)) {
                return AMERICAN_EXPRESS;
            } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DISCOVER)) {
                return DISCOVER;
            } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_JCB)) {
                return JCB;
            } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_DINERS_CLUB)) {
                return DINERS_CLUB;
            } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_VISA)) {
                return VISA;
            } else if (StripeTextUtils.hasAnyPrefix(number, PREFIXES_MASTERCARD)) {
                return MASTERCARD;
            } else {
                return UNKNOWN;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;

    }
```

Comment: [code]Error:(391, 13) error: no suitable constructor found for Stripe(no arguments)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)[/code]

Comment: Can you please share your complete source File ?

Comment: [code]Error:(391, 13) error: no suitable constructor found for Stripe(no arguments)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(Context,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)[/code]

Comment: Please Create a Stripe Object like this  Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this); and then use the object to access the Stripe Functions like stripe.createToken()     , The Stripe Constructor is updated

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean validation = card.validateCard();
    if (validation) {
        AndyUtils.showCustomProgressDialog(activity,
                getString(R.string.adding_payment), false, null);
        new Stripe().createToken(card, Const.PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                new TokenCallback() {
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        // getTokenList().addToList(token);
                        // AndyUtils.showToast(token.getId(), activity);
                        String lastFour = etCreditCardNum.getText()
                                .toString();
                        lastFour = lastFour.substring(lastFour.length() - 4);
                        addCard(token.getId(), lastFour);
                        // finishProgress();
                    }

                    public void onError(Exception error) {
                        AndyUtils.showToast(getString(R.string.text_error), activity);
                        // finishProgress();
                        AndyUtils.removeCustomProgressDialog();
```